# Node.js require classes using string variable names

Tags: node.js

I have an array containing class names all uppercase and another class where I want to generate an object storing these classes.

Is there away to populate the object using require from  the string filenames? I am getting an error when trying to do so and I am not sure its even possible.

```js
const STRATEGY_NAMES = process.env.STRATEGY_NAMES.split(',');
const STRATEGY_CLASSES = {};

for(let i=0; i< STRATEGY_NAMES.length;i++){
  STRATEGY_CLASSES[i] : require(STRATEGY_NAMES[i].toLowerCase()
}
```

So later in the code I could call new STRATEGY_CLASSESindex;

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting when you attempt to run this code? By the looks of it, it is likely a syntax error of some kind.

This line: `STRATEGY_CLASSES[i] : require(STRATEGY_NAMES[i].toLowerCase()` should probably be something like `STRATEGY_CLASSES[i] = require(STRATEGY_NAMES[i].toLowerCase())`.

Comment: Also, you may find it more convenient to index the `STRATEGY_CLASSES` object with string names rather than integer indexes. That way, you can lookup your classes by name, rather than number.

Comment: You are also missing the closing `)` from your `require`. Also, if you insist on making them indexed, maybe all your need is a `map` and not an object, as its keys wont be enumarable.